# Direct read-in in R (without file)

Tags: r, read.table

a simple question here. I knew this once but somehow can't find it anymore and it bothers me... :
How do you read-in small data directly in the source code? 
Something like:

```
mydata <- read.table(
"tree size age
A 3 3
B 4 6
C 12 80
D 16 23", 
header=TRUE)
```

I know that I could just define the data.frame directly, but the clearness of the blank text is very nice and very often I can copy it from somewhere like that.

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you should look into [Tibbles](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/). You can create a tibble in the same way as above (almost the same), then convert it to a data frame if required. Take a look at the last example.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. That's a cool tool. I am just sure that it worked in an easy way with data.frames and without additional packages.

Comment: Just use the `text` argument: `read.table(text="<data.frame content here>")`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read.table` has a `text` argument you can use:

```r
mydata <- read.table(
  text = "tree size age
  A 3 3
  B 4 6
  C 12 80
  D 16 23", 
  header=TRUE)

mydata
#>   tree size age
#> 1    A    3   3
#> 2    B    4   6
#> 3    C   12  80
#> 4    D   16  23
```

Created on 2018-07-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

could also use read.csv:

```
s<-"tree size age
A 3 3
B 4 6
C 12 80
D 16 23"
read.csv(textConnection(s),header=TRUE,sep=" ")
tree size age
1    A    3   3
2    B    4   6
3    C   12  80
4    D   16  23
```